Let $a_0,a_1,\dots,a_{n+1}$ be an arithmetic sequence. Prove the following holds: $a_1^3+a_2^3+\dots+a_n^3=\dfrac{(a_na_{n+1})^2 -(a_1a_0)^2}{4d}$
Let  $a_0,a_1,\dots,a_n,a_{n+1}$  be an arithmetic sequence. Prove that the following holds:
$$a_1^3 + a_2^3 + a_3^3 +\dots+ a_n^3 = \frac{(a_na_{n+1})^2 - (a_1a_0)^2}{4d}$$
where $d$ is the common difference of the sequence.
I tried approaching this problem with sum of sequence $1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 + \dots + n^3$. When I want to find this sum I use:
$$(n + 1)^4 - n^4 = 4n^3 + 6n^2 + 4n + 1$$
$$For\, n = 1: \,\,\,2^4 - 1^4 = 4 * 1^3 + 6 * 1^2 + 4 * 1 +1$$
$$For\, n = 2: \,\,\,3^4 - 2^4 = 4 * 2^3 + 6 * 2^2 + 4 * 2 +1$$
$$For\, n = 3: \,\,\,4^4 - 3^4 = 4 * 3^3 + 6 * 3^2 + 4 * 3 +1$$
$$For\, n = n: \,\,\,(n+1)^4 - n^4 = 4n^3 + 6n^2 + 4n +1$$
If we sum all terms for every new $n$, $n^4$ will cancel previous $(n+1)^4$, thus we are left with:
$$(n+1)^4 - 1 = 4 (1^3 + 2^3 + \dots + n^3) + 6 (1^2 + 2^2 + \dots + n^2) + 4 (1 + 2 + \dots + n) + n$$
$$S_n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} = 1 + 2 + \dots + n \quad\text{and}\quad S_{n^2} = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} = 1^2 + 2^2 + \dots + n^2$$
When we plug and simplify these two sums in first expression we get:
$$S_{n^3} = 1^3 + 2^3 + \dots + n^3 = \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$$
The problem with this is that this only works if $a_1 = 1$  and $d = 1$. I tried same process with $a_1$ and $d$:
$$(n + d)^4 - n^4 = 4n^3d + 6n^2d^2 + 4nd^3 + d^4$$
After doing $n = a_1, a_2, a_3 , \dots , a_n $ I get:
$$a_{n+1}^4 - a_1^4 = 4d(a_1^3 + a_2^3 + \dots + a_n^3) + 6d^2(a_1^2 + a_2^2 + \dots + a_n^2) + 4d^3(a_1 + a_2 + \dots + a_n) + nd^4$$
But this time I can't use $\,S_n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}\, and \,\,S_{n^2} = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ because they only apply for $a_1 = 1 \,\,$ and $\,\, d = 1$. I also tried using mathematical induction to prove $a_1^3 + a_2^3 + a_3^3 +\dots+ a_n^3 = \frac{(a_na_{n+1})^2 - (a_1a_0)^2}{4d} \,\,$ but simplifying was too complicated. If anyone has an idea how to solve this problem I would be very grateful to see it. Sorry for bad english and long question.

I suggest writing $a_i = a_0 + i\cdot d$ and expanding both sides out. It is a not too complicated once you already had for the formulas for $S_n$, $S_{n^2}$ and $S_{n^3}$

We prove that the following statement, $P(n)$:
$$a_1^3 + a_2^3 + a_3^3 +...+ a_n^3 = \frac{(a_na_{n+1})^2 - (a_1a_0)^2}{4d}$$
is true for all $n$ via induction.
I leave the basis case to the reader.
Suppose $P(n)$ is true for some $n.$ Then we must show statement $P(n+1)$ is true, that is, we must show that
$$a_1^3 + a_2^3 + a_3^3 +...+ a_n^3 + a_{n+1}^3 = \frac{(a_{n+1}a_{n+2})^2 - (a_1a_0)^2}{4d}$$
To this end:
$$ \frac{(a_{n+1}a_{n+2})^2 - (a_1a_0)^2}{4d} = \frac{(a_{n+1}a_{n+2})^2 - (a_na_{n+1})^2}{4d} + \color{blue}{\frac{(a_na_{n+1})^2 -(a_1a_0)^2}{4d}}$$
$$ = \frac{a_{n+1}^2 \color{red}{(a_{n+2} - a_n)}(a_{n+2} + a_n)}{4d} + \color{blue}{a_1^3 + a_2^3 + a_3^3 +...+ a_n^3} $$
$$ = \frac{a_{n+1}^2 \color{red}{(2d)}( (a_{n+1}+d) + (a_{n+1}-d))}{4d} + a_1^3 + a_2^3 + a_3^3 +...+ a_n^3$$
$$ = \frac{a_{n+1}^2 (2d)( 2a_{n+1})}{4d} + a_1^3 + a_2^3 + a_3^3 +...+ a_n^3. $$

Actually, that the first term is equal to $ a_{n+1}^3$ follows by strong induction on the AP $a_n,  a_{n+1}, a_{n+2} $ (Or you might recognize it as the base case). So, you've essentially proved the base case, despite saying that it's left to the reader :)

Thank you for your solution. I really appreciate it!

@CalvinLin the basis case confused me, so I couldn't be bothered to figure it out. I left it to the reader (lol).

Lemma: For a 3-term Arithmetic Progression $a_0, a_1, a_2$ with common difference $d$,
$$ a_1^3 = \frac{ (a_2a_1)^2 - (a_1a_0)^2 }{ 4d}.$$
Proof: Substitute in $a_0 = a, a_1 = a+d, a_2 = a+2d$, which gives us
$RHS =  a_1^2 \times \frac{ (a+2d)^2 - a^2 } { 4d} = a_1^2 \times \frac {4ad+4d^2 } { 4d} = a_1^2 \times (a+d) = a_1^3 = LHS$.
Corollary: Applying this to each 3 consecutive terms of an $n+2$ term Arithmetic Progression $a_0, a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n, a_{n+1}$ with common difference $d$, we get the telescoping series:
$$ \begin{array} { l l l l l } & & a_1^3 & + a_2^3 & + \ldots & + a_n^3 \\
 & = & \frac{ (a_2a_1)^2 - (a_1a_0)^2 }{ 4d} & + \frac{ (a_3a_2)^2 - (a_2a_1)^2 }{ 4d} &  + \ldots & +\frac{ (a_{n+1}a_n)^2 - (a_na_{n-1})^2 }{ 4d}\\
& = & \frac{ (a_{n+1}a_n)^2 - (a_1a_0)^2 }{ 4d} \end{array}. $$
Note: Instead of the telescoping series, one could treat this as an induction proof. The Lemma should be recognizable as the base case.

Thank you so much :)
